# Restriction of cuspidal representations of GL(2) to the Borel subgroup

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field and let $B$ be the standard Borel subgroup of $GL(2, \mathbb{F}_q)$ consisting of upper triangular matrices.  Is there an explicit description of the restriction to $B$ of the cuspidal representations of $GL(2, \mathbb{F}_q)$?  All the constructions of the cuspidal representations I know are fairly complicated, but for what I’m doing I only need to know their restrictions to $B$, so I was hoping there was something easier.

Comment: You can find a construction in chapter 9 of my notes https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~sjw47/2023Lectures.pdf. More precisely you want the things I call $\mu_\theta$ at the end of section 9.3.

Comment: @SimonWadsley: You calculate the character table (which can also be found in many other places), but on page 67 you say re the cuspidal representations “we won’t be able to explicitly construct the representations”.

Comment: If you look closely you'll see that I do construct the cuspidal representations _after restriction to $B$_ though not on the whole of $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$. They are constructed exactly as Paul Broussous indicates in his answer but more details are provided. You can see from the characters that the $\mu_\theta$ which are constructed as representations coincide with the restrictions of the cuspidal representations.

Comment: @SimonWadsley: Ah, I understand what you were getting at now!  I am working on my phone, so I didn’t see the edit you made to your comment giving a more precise reference until after I replied.

Comment: @Linda. There is no simple construction of cuspidal representations. You have Deligne-Lusztig theory which involves very sophisticated tools from algebraic geometry. You also have the construction via the Weil representation (in characteristic not $2$). This latter is simpler.

Comment: @Linda. Using the Bruhat decomposition $G=B\cup BwB$, you see that to specify a cuspidal, you have to give the action of $w=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right)$ on the Kirillov space $\mu$. This is the difficult part!

Comment: @PaulBroussous: Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Z$ be the center of $G={\rm GL}(2,{\mathbb F}_q )$ and
$$
M=\left\{ \left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)\in G\right\}
$$
be the mirabolic subgroup of $G$, so that $B=ZM$. Fix a non trivial character $\psi$ of $U$. By the theory of Kirillov models, the representation $\mu ={\rm Ind}_U^M \, \psi$ is irreducible (of dimension $q-1$), and for any irreducible representation $\pi$ of $G$, of dimension $>1$, we have
$$
{\rm dim}\, {\rm Hom}_M (\pi ,\mu ) =1
$$
If $\pi$ is cuspidal, then ${\rm dim}\, \pi =q-1$, so that, $\pi_{\mid M}\simeq \mu$. So the restriction of $\pi$ to $M$ does not depends on the irreducible cuspidal representation $\pi$. The restriction of those $\pi$ to $B$ only depends on the central character $\omega_\pi$ of $\pi$.

Comment: This is really nice!  Two questions: 1. Is there a friendly place to read about Kirillov models (I’m not a representation theorist)?  and 2. I assume in your last sentence you mean the restriction of $\pi$ to $B$, right?

Comment: @Linda. For point 2, you're right! I corrected the mistake.  For point 1, I don't know.